# Android testing with foreign languages

Tags: android

I developed a small BLE configuration application for a customer (app configures a BLE enabled embedded control).  He's hearing back from one of his over seas customers (Japan) that the application will not install.  We've targeted Android 4.4 as our minimum SDK and have tested it in the US on Android devices running everything up to and including Marshmallow (6.0) and have had no issues.

The customer insists that applications have to be "specially developed" for Japan on Android.  There are no text boxes on the application.  Just some check boxes and spinners to select the appropriate numerical values.

I understand that the few LABELS haven't been translated to Japanese (or any foreign language for that matter) but that wouldn't prevent the application from installing, correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that there's some limitation in the Japanese Play Store. Which would make this affirmation senseful: `The customer insists that applications have to be "specially developed" for Japan on Android.`

Comment: Good suggestion Frank.  At the moment he is just sending the application to his overseas customers as an .apk file and having them side load it, that's when he says the application won't load.

Comment: Or maybe the limitation is on the phone? Maybe the Android ROMs in Japan are subject to implicit limitations? I guess you could try with a Japanese stock ROM. Or a workaround could be to momentarily localize THEIR devices to another country (say, US) and try to install the app. Only then re-localize the devices to Japan.